# Trying to add a HTML code using JQuery insertBefore() method, but the HTML string get's jumbled up after running

Tags: jquery, event-handling, handler

In this loop, I'm trying to add an event handler to each "count". The event handler calls a function "hideAll()", whose input value is "count".

I am doing so by adding HTML code under the ID "next", using JQuery's insertBefore() method.

```
for (count=1; count<=3; count++)
{    

$('<a href="#" onclick="hideAll(' + count + ');return false;">' + count + '</a>').insertBefore("#next");

}
```

So when I run it, it gets added, but for some weird reason, it get's added like this:

```
<a onclick="hideAll(1);return false;" href="#">1</a>
```

The string *href="#"* is getting moved over to the end. I can't figure out why.

I tried checking the quotation marks and everything. Everything seems perfect, no idea why it's doing that.

Comment: it doestn't make any difference

Comment: what are yo using to view the added element? Some consoles reorder tags.

Comment: Chrome. So maybe there is something wrong with the hideAll() function I am calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you viewing it in?

Some browsers, when viewing the dom, shows you its "final" source after it has interpreted the markup.

Make sure you "View Page Source", and not "Inspect Elements" to get the pure pre-interpreted markup.

Ultimately, though, the order of attributes are irrelevant, so it should be fine for your purposes?

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

I tried the one with the corrected quote, still does not work. It's even more jumbled up than before.

I thought it would be fine too, but then it does not do what it's supposed. I just simplified the loop here, but the hideAll() function is supposed to hide all images except the specified one, etc. 

Yeh, I am using Firebug. But even viewing the whole source code, it shows the same error.

Comment: Elaborate on the error so others can help, because the HTML is fine. :) And yeh, ignore my previous post with the quote, I read the post wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the jQuery source, this is what gets called when you pass in your string,

```
if ( jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
    selector = [ document.createElement( ret[1] ) ];
    jQuery.fn.attr.call( selector, context, true );
} else {
        selector = [ doc.createElement( ret[1] ) ];
}
```

So whatever the broswer spits out of `document.createElement()` is what jQuery is putting on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter for you?

The thing is that code

```
$('<a href="#" onclick="hideAll(' + count + ');return false;">' + count + '</a>').insertBefore("#next");
```

does not insert raw HTML before #next tag.

The command

```
$('<a href="#" onclick="hideAll(' + count + ');return false;">' + count + '</a>');
```

creates DOM element in the memory and wraps it into jQuery selector. Then it being inserted into DOM tree of page. And how it is showed to you as string is up to browser.

Comment: Hmn, ok, so everyone is saying here that it does not matter if it shows jumbled up, right? Then maybe there is something wrong with another function...

Comment: Yes, the problem is defenitly in some other place.